# Can I get the running time of an application? [Android]

Tags: java, android

I'm interested in getting the running time of any application (not my own) in Android. Is there any way to do that? More specifically, I'm interested in both lifetime running (since it was installed) and since it was last started.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also monitoring the foregrounds applications, for example you can create a scheduled service that check applications list and check the state.

```
ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> allTasks = mgr.getRunningTasks(showLimit);
/* each all applications */
for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo aTask : allTasks) 
{                  
    Log.i("MyApp", "Task: " + aTask.baseActivity.getClassName()); 

}
```

you can found [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html) about RunningTaskInfo object.

**Is possibile monitoring service with:**

```
ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> allTasks = mgr.getRunningServices(showLimit);
/* each all service */
for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo aTask : allTasks)
{
    Log.i("MyApp", "Task: " + aTask.activeSince);

}
```

Comment: There isn't a specific way to check running time of an application, is possibile with services (see over). A possibile warkaround is to create your logic, a custom service started every X seconds where you check open application, but it isn't accurate

Comment: I'm not interested to have very accurate values (to the second). Minutes/hours would do. Anyway, if I do it with a custom service that checks every, let's say, 3 minutes, would that be noticeable in the phone usage speed? Also, sorry if I ask anything stupid, this is the first time I make an Android app.